# replacing string with space in razor

Tags: c#, razor, str-replace

I'm putting some values into my div class from check box list. When one check box is selected it works as it should be but when two or more check boxes are selected it puts the " , " in between each value when the code is executed e.g Class="class1,class2 element". So question is, how can I replace " , " with space between two classes? Below is my code:

```
@{
var playerHref="http://player.vimeo.com/video/";
}
<!--gallery start-->
<div id="container" class="grid_12 isotope">
  @foreach (LoopItem i in GetLoop("ItemPublisher:Items.List")){

  <div id="box" class="@i.GetValue("ItemPublisher:Item.checkboxes") element">

    <a href="@playerHref@i.GetValue("itempublisher:Item.Vimeoid")" rel="Shadowbox;height=540;width=960" target="_blank">
      <img id="box-img" src="@i.GetValue("ItemPublisher:Item.GalleryImage")" title="play" alt="play">
      </a>
  </div>
    }
</div>
<!--gallery ends-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the class of your `div#box` like this:

```
<div id="box" class="@i.GetValue("ItemPublisher:Item.checkboxes").ToString().Replace(',',' ') element">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking something like:

```
ItemPublisher:Item.checkboxes.Replace(',',' ');
```

or perhaps

```
ItemPublisher:Item.checkboxes.ToString().Replace(',',' ');
```

Finally

```
@i.GetValue("ItemPublisher:Item.checkboxes").Replace(',',' ')
```

Hopefully one of these will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
@i.Replace(" ", ",")
```